# Why won't this SQL run properly from the Google Analytics certificate Coursera course?

Tags: sql, syntax

[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmVVs.png)
[screenshot of instructor's demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGpZB.png)

I copied the text from the video taking into account capitalizations. Why does it give me this error message? It's so confusing.

I tried changing the capitalization of the table and changing the single quotes to backticks and removing the single quotes.

Comment: And how did the error message change when you changed your SQL statements?

Comment: Also, please add your full code AND the error message into  your question itself. Don't just add screenshots of code or text.

Comment: Sorry I realized the instructor used backticks for all of the table names instead of single quotes, so I changed them to backticks and it worked (except for some other errors which occurred but I fixed those according to the instructions). I don't get why that caused the error though because I thought the table names could use single quotes.

Comment: could you please add your error message and your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.